# Consumer/producer locking GUI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I made a sample Consumer/Producer thread application, so I can learn how to properly use it.

I want it to allow for one thread to send commands to the GUI thread, to update the GUI with content.

I have it working, but there's one small issue. The GUI thread is my consumer thread, so I have it always checking for new commands (using a while loop). The issue is that because of this while loop, the GUI never displays because it's always stuck in the while loop. Note that the string Queue will eventually be replaced with a more complex object (one that holds data & command type).

I'm not sure how else to allow the GUI thread to consume commands without interrupting GUI functionality. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my Form1.cs code (the form only contains 1 RichTextBox for showing output called OutputBox).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MultiThreading
{
   class ThreadCommandQueue
   {
      public static ThreadCommandQueue instance = new ThreadCommandQueue();

      private Queue<string> m_queue;
      private Object m_lock;

      public static ThreadCommandQueue GetInstance()
      {
         return instance;
      }

      private ThreadCommandQueue()
      {
         m_queue = new Queue<string>();
         m_lock = new Object();
      }

      public void Add(
         string data_to_add)
      {
         lock (m_lock)
         {
            m_queue.Enqueue(data_to_add);
         }
      }

      public string Get()
      {
         lock (m_lock)
         {
            if (m_queue.Count > 0)
            {
               return m_queue.Dequeue();
            }

            return null;
         }
      }
   }

   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void PopulateThreadCommandQueue()
      {
         int i = 0;
         while(true)
         {
            ThreadCommandQueue.GetInstance().Add("Item #: " + i.ToString());
            i++;
         }
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         // Create the Command Queue....
         ThreadCommandQueue.GetInstance();

         // Create a Testing Producer Thread
         Thread ProducerThread = new Thread(PopulateThreadCommandQueue);
         ProducerThread.Start();

         // The GUI thread is the Consumer, so keep checking the CommandQueue for data...
         while(true)
         {
            string latest = ThreadCommandQueue.GetInstance().Get();
            if(latest != null)
            {
               OutputBox.Text += latest + "\n";
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. If the point of the exercise is to explicitly implement a consumer, that object will have to execute in a thread other than the UI thread. Simple as that. You just can't block the UI thread, for anything. However, the UI thread is itself a kind of consumer thread; it will execute any delegate you pass to the `Control.Invoke()` or `Control.BeginInvoke()` method. This _implicit_ use of the already-existing UI thread consumer implementation would be suitable for most real-world scenarios, and may in your case. But your question simply isn't clear enough to know

Comment: Try use BlockingCollection, in your code you waste cpu when read. Of course in some cases spinwait is appropriated, but not in this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ConcurrentQueue. So no locking is required to add and get from Queue.

Also you in real time you will not receive commands continuously from UI thread (while loop). If you have such scenario use a separate thread to receive outcome.

Then from the receivers thread you can update UI using Invoke command, as below.

```
//This method called from receiver thread 
public void UpdateForm(Data d) 
{
   if(this.InvokeRequired) 
   {
      this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.UpdateFormUI(r)));
   }
   else 
   {
      this.UpdateFormUI(data)
   }
}

public void UpdateFormUI(Data d)
{
   //Does actual ui update
}
```

Comment: No, it's not thread-safe. The docs say "Use ConcurrentQueue<T> or ConcurrentStack<T> if you need to access the collection from multiple threads concurrently."

Comment: Awesome, thank you! You make it seems like I have another option other than using a while loop. Is there a way for me to somehow only try to read a command when there is one available?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem here is that you need to poll the message loop all the time to make GUI working and you also need to poll your IPC command queue all the time to make your commands working and you need this polling to happen at the same time on the same thread.

There are multiple ways to resolve this, but the easiest would be to process the message loop and when there is nothing to process, do your IPC command queue processing. For WinForms application this would be something like:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Application.Idle += (sender, eargs) => ProcessCommands();
}

private void ProcessCommands()
{
    while(true)
    {
      string latest = ThreadCommandQueue.GetInstance().Get();
      if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(latest)) return;
      OutputBox.Text += latest + "\n";
    }
}
```